# Как посчитать элементы массива от a до b?

Tags: c

Как посчитать кол-во элементов от a до b, допустим массив из 10 элементов `[1,2,4,5,13,16,19,21,23,10]`, нужно посчитать элементы от 4 до 21 (т.е. `4, 5, 13, 16, 19, 21`, ответ должен получится: "6").

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 200
int main() {
    int i, n, m[N], a, b, elCount;
    setlocale(0, "");
    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    }
    if (n > N) {
        printf("Вы вышли за границу массива");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Введите элементы массива:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &m[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (m[i] == i * i) {
            a = m[i];
        }
        if (!(m[i] % 3)) {
            b = m[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = a; i < b; i++) {
        elCount += 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", elCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В a и b нужно сохранять не значение элемента массива, а его индекс. Тогда  elCount=b-a+1.

Comment: Вам сначала нужно найти индексы значений 4 и 21 или эти индексы уже заданы?

Comment: 4 и 21 находятся в двух if по условиям задачи (первый элемент равен квадрату номера, а последний кратен 3). То что написал, Ddd - правильно, всё работает.

Comment: ~~Ещё бы хотелось узнать, как затем просуммировать эти элементы.~~
Сам смог сделать.
Нужно сделать цикл
` for(i=a+1;i<b;i++){
    sum += m[i]
}
sum = sum + m[a] + m[b];`

Comment: Расширьте границы цикла, и не надо будет отдельно добавлять + m[a] + m[b]